# Nuxt How to set baseURL in dev or production

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

This seems like a simple Nuxt question, but I just can't figure it out.

When running "NPM run dev" I want to set the Axios baseURL to "localhost/api" and when running from the dist folder after "NPM run generate" I want the baseURL to be "/api".

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 21):

This is the way to do it through the `nuxt.config.js`:

```
let development = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

module.exports = {
  axios: {
    baseURL: development ? 'http://localhost:3001/api' : 'https://domain/api'
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
}
```

As you can see, you should specify full URL of your backend, including domain (except SPA-only mode).

And don't forget to install @nuxtjs/axios as dependency to try the example.

Comment: Worked perfect!

Comment: @SteveO Cool. In this case you'd better mark this question as resolved, just saying

Comment: Not Working Bro

Answer (score 4):

you can also set api from outside (eg package.json scripts) by env variable

my package.json fragment (there is additional complexity when browser uses different
api url then server side rendering, still all is supported by Nuxt itself with variables API_URL_BROWSER and API_URL)

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev-prodapi": "API_URL=https://kairly.com/api nuxt",
    "dev": "API_URL=http://localhost:8000/api nuxt",
    "dev-spa-prodapi": "API_URL=https://kairly.com/api nuxt --spa",
    "dev-spa": "API_URL=http://localhost:8000/api nuxt --spa",
    "build": "API_URL_BROWSER=https://kairly.com/api API_URL=https://internal-apihost/api/ nuxt build --modern=server",
    "start": "API_URL_BROWSER=https://kairly.com/api API_URL=https://internal-apihost/api/ nuxt start --modern=server",
```

and using no axios section in nuxt config at all.

Answer (score 1):

In **Nuxt 3** we can use a `.env` file. Here's the [doc](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-runtime-config#environment-variables).

```
# .env

API_URL=http://localhost:8080/api
```

```js
// nuxt.config

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    runtimeConfig: {
        // Private keys are only available on the server
        apiSecret: '123',
        // Public keys that are exposed to the client
        public: {
            apiUrl: process.env.API_URL
        }
    }
})
```

```js
// MyComponent.vue

<script setup>
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()
  console.log(config.public.apiUrl)
</script>
```