# Nuxt.js - How to set API base URL?

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to set the API base URL in Nuxt.js. I've used DreaMinder's answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770792/nuxt-how-to-set-baseurl-in-dev-or-production).

I get no errors but when I try to hit any endpoints from my app I get a 404 error (the endpoints to exist). The only way I can get my code to work is to put the full URL in each axios request.

This is my `nuxt.config.js`

```
import pkg from './package'
require('dotenv').config()

let development = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    // title: pkg.name,
    title: "AppName",
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
  },

  /*
   ** Customize the progress-bar color
   */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: [],

  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   */
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vue-cookies',
    '~/plugins/vee-validate',
    '~/plugins/moment',
    '~/plugins/vue-truncate-filter',
    '~/plugins/numeral'
  ],

  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   */
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
    // baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:5000/v1'
    baseURL: development ? 'http://localhost:5000/v1' : 'https://api.appname.com/v1'
  },

  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // Doc: https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation
    'nuxt-buefy'
  ],

  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      // Run ESLint on save
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the app is trying to use the front end URL instead of the API. So instead of hitting ```http://localhost:5000/v1/resources/users/login``` it's trying to use ```http://localhost:3000/resources/users/login``` which doesn't exist.

Comment: I just added answer to referenced original question how to use API_URL variable. You can try it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had same errors.
But I fixed it to use proxy.
Please try it.
Here is my nuxt.config.js.

```
... ... ...
 modules: [
    ... ... ...
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
    // baseURL: process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:3000/',
    proxy:true,
  },
 proxy:{
    '/api/': { target: [your base url], pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''}, changeOrigin: true }
  },
... ... ...
```

And You can call the endpoint using this.

```
let data= await this.$axios.get(
          '/api/[your endpoint url],
          {
            params: {     
              ... ... ...
            },
            headers: {
              ... ... ...
            },
          }
        );
```

You need to install @nuxtjs/proxy npm module.
Please try use this.